# SpresenseのSDカードスロットに関して

Tags: spresense

Spresenseのmicro SDカードスロットが外れてしまいました．
テープで補強したりと応急処置をとっていたのですが，
しっかり固定するのは厳しく，SDカードの認識が甘くなっています．

どこかで修理することはできますでしょうか．
また，何か補強策はございますでしょうか．

Answer (score 0):

修理できるかできないかで言えば
基板の修理業者というものがありますので修理できるでしょうが、
おそらく買い替えたほうが安いです。